# Prolog, trying to append 2 lists but kept on getting false

Tags: list, prolog, append, rules

```
lists([a,b,c]).

first(F):-lists([F,_,_]).  
second(S):-lists([_,S,_]).  
last(L):-lists([_,_,L]).  

sf(X):-append(second(X),first(X),X).

?-sf(X) //returns false
```

I'm basically trying to get a return X=[c,a] but kept on getting false.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog is not a functional language. When you write `append(second(X),first(X),X)`, the first and second argument are not replaced by, respectively, `lists([_,S,_])` and `lists([F,_,_])`. If you try instead:

```
sf(List) :-
    second(Second),
    first(First),
    append(Second, First, List).
```

you will get a failure:

```
| ?- sf(List).

no
```

To understand why, let's trace the call in the debugger:

```
| ?- trace.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

yes
{trace}
| ?- sf(List).
      1    1  Call: sf(_279) ? 
      2    2  Call: second(_346) ? 
      3    3  Call: lists([_332,_334,_336]) ? 
      3    3  Exit: lists([a,b,c]) ? 
      2    2  Exit: second(b) ? 
      4    2  Call: first(_400) ? 
      5    3  Call: lists([_386,_388,_390]) ? 
      5    3  Exit: lists([a,b,c]) ? 
      4    2  Exit: first(a) ? 
      6    2  Call: append(b,a,_279) ? 
      6    2  Fail: append(b,a,_279) ? 
      1    1  Fail: sf(_279) ? 

(1 ms) no
{trace}
```

The de facto standard `append/3` predicate, usually available as a library predicate or as a built-in predicate, takes lists as arguments, but here we're calling it with the atoms `a` and `b`. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. First of all, a call like:

```
sf(X) :- append(second(X), first(X), X).
```

makes no sense at all: here `second/1` and `first/1` are treated as *functors*. These do not have anything to do with the `second/1` and `first/1` *predicate*. `append/3` thus receives three terms: `second(X)`, `first(X)` and `X`. It however expects lists, so that means it expects the empty list constant `[]`, or the "cons" functor (like `[H|T]`, we could see this as the `[]/2` functor).

We thus do not want to construct a functor, we want to *unify* a list with a variable, and then append these. So we can rewrite this to:

```
sf(X) :- second(X), first(X), append(X, X, X).
```

But now it is still incorrect, here we unify both the first and second list with `X`, and we append it to `X`, `append(X, X, X)` can only succeed in one case: if `X` is the empty list, since appending two empty lists results in an empty list.

```
sf(X) :- second(S), first(F), append(S, F, X).
```

But it will still fail. The reason is that your `first/1` and `second/1` predicate do *not* return lists, these return elements. Indeed:

```
?- first(X).
X = a.
```

You can not `append/3` two constants `b` and `a` together, you can append *lists* with `a` and `b` together, so:

```
sf(X) :- second(S), first(F), append([S], [F], X).
```

The `first/1` and `second/1` predicate are also *too specific*: if `lists/1` contains a list with four elements, then these predicates will fail, so I propose you refactor these.